# Has $\phi(n)=\phi(n+1)=\phi(n+2)$ the only solution $n=5186\ $?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Let $\phi(n)$ denote the totient-function

> Is the only solution of $$\phi(n)=\phi(n+1)=\phi(n+2)$$ $n=5186$ ? I did not find another solution upto $n=10^8$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [OEIS A001274](http://oeis.org/A001274):

---

> Lal-Gillard and Firoozbakht ask whether there is another pair of consecutive integers in this sequence, apart from a(16) + 1 = a(17) = 5187, see [link](http://www.primepuzzles.net/puzzles/puzz_466.htm). - M. F. Hasler, Jan 05 2011

---

> Up to 10^13 there are 10755 terms, and no further consecutive pairs like (5186, 5187). - Giovanni Resta, Feb 27 2014